# What flags should I run with monerod to be the most helpful to the network?

Tags: monerod

Additionally, do I have to port-forward in my router to let others sync off me?

Answer (score 2):

The p2p interface doesn't require port forwarding at the router but the RPC interface does for remote access. Therefore if you wanted to help users needing a public remote node (e.g. for using a light wallet), you'd need to port forward to whatever RPC port you decide to listen on (`--rpc-bind-port`, the default being 18081). If you're going to do this, I suggest also using `--restricted-rpc`.

Now the p2p traffic, there are a couple of settings you can tweak which affects both the usefulness of your node to others and your bandwidth:

```
--out-peers arg (=-1)                 set max number of out peers
--in-peers arg (=-1)                  set max number of in peers
--limit-rate-up arg (=2048)           set limit-rate-up [kB/s]
--limit-rate-down arg (=8192)         set limit-rate-down [kB/s]
--limit-rate arg (=-1)                set limit-rate [kB/s]
```

For example, if the node is exhausting all your bandwidth, lower `--limit-rate-up`; if you have plenty of spare bandwidth, up it.

If you have *significant* bandwidth to share, *and* are opening up RPC, *and* you are going to maintain the node, you could also list your node on sites like [moneroworld](https://moneroworld.com/#nodes).

Comment: Can you more clearly give what this would all look line in one `./monerod` line? And just to be clear - with that line I would port forward 18081?

Comment: Port forwarding has to be done on your router, not on the machine running monerod. And `./monerod --restricted-rpc --limit-rate 8192` is an example of standard node, listening on p2p and RPC ports (18080 and 18081 respectively), with restricted RPC (so view only) and an up & down limit of 8192kB/s.

Comment: I'm going to create a new question since this is getting a bit off topic now -