# What ports should I forward on my router to be most useful to the network?

Tags: monerod, nodes, ports

I'm running `monerod --rpc-bind-port 18081 --restricted-rpc`, and want other people to be able to sync off my nodes. If I port-forward on my router, which ports should I open?

Edit: According to https://canyouseeme.org/, I already have port 18080 open. It seems `monerod` created this automatically. Am I already good to go?

Answer (score 3):

As I [answered](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11746/7493) to your previous question, you do not *need* to forward any ports for the **p2p** interface. This is the interface **nodes** use to send each other data, such as blocks. transactions and peerlists. Other nodes can sync with you fine *without* router port forwarding because when *you* initiate an outbound connection to a peer, it is kept open, thus data can be both sent and received. More important for p2p traffic is how many connected peers you allow and how much bandwidth you allow. Settings already [explained](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/11746/7493).

**Wallets** however need to talk to nodes over the **RPC** interface. Thus, if you want to help *wallet* users who don't run their own node, you can forward the RPC port to your RPC listening port (in your example this is port **18081**). This you do on your *router*, normally under a section named *"port mapping"* or similar. You will be filling in details to tell your router to *"make requests coming to port 18081 go to computer your.local.ip port 18081"*

Comment: Do I have to start the RPC as well to do this? Using canyouseeme.org, 18081 is showing as offline, even though it's forwarded.

Comment: RPC is started by default. When you start the daemon, you will get a line like `core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081` as one of the log messages.